# Extending Ackermann's map to cardinals

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

Ackermann found [an explicit canonical bijection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hereditarily_finite_set) between $\omega$ and $V_{\omega}$.

Is it possible to somewhat explicitly define such bijections between $\kappa$ and $V_{\kappa}$ for an inaccessible cardinal $\kappa$ (possibly with extending or modifying Ackermann's idea)?

Comment: Interesting question, but the point of Ackermann's map is not only it is a bijection but also a bi-interpretation between $\mathsf{PA}$ and finitary $\mathsf{ZF}$ (which comprises $\mathsf{ZF}$ without Infinity plus the negation of infinity and the existence of transitive closure for all sets.) Could we expect the same for an inaccessible version of Ackermann's interpretation?

Comment: Explicitly? No. Because if AC fails there might not be any such bijection.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Well, suppose AC holds. I wrote "explicitly" because I don't want the "well, they have the same cardinality" answers. What I am after is a generalization of Ackermann's idea using ordinal/cardinal arithmetic. But any map which does not cheat by well-ordering the whole thing/hugse sets is acceptable I guess.

Comment: But that's the point. The only way to use AC here is to somehow say "just well-order the whole thing". You can be coy about it and well-order the ranks one by one, and stack them one on top of the other. But at the end of the day, that's just what it is. I'd dare say that in some sense the well-ordering of $L$ is somehow a generalisation of Ackermann's bijection.

Comment: Also, as far as "explicit" goes, you'd somehow expect it to be relatively internal, so that $V_\kappa$ can recognise it. And even if not, you may at least end up with this when $\kappa$ is a large enough large cardinal. And of course, that means that global choice holds internally in $V_\kappa$, which is not even a consequence of $\sf ZFC$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I think your comments should be an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Off the bat, the answer is negative. It of course consistent that $\kappa$ is strongly inaccessible (in the strong sense of the term), and $\sf AC$ fails in $V_\kappa$, so there is no bijection between $\kappa$ and $V_\kappa$.

This tells you that some use of choice is necessary, and that it cannot be "too explicit". But more than just that. The Ackermann map is internal to $V_\omega$, and any such "explicit map", even if relying on some choice somehow, would end up being internal to $V_\kappa$. So that means that $V_\kappa$ is not just a model of $\sf ZFC$, but also of global choice. However, we know that this is not always the case. For example, if we add two infinite sets of Cohen subsets to every regular cardinal below $\kappa$, then there is no definable linear ordering of $V_\kappa$ (where definable is "internally definable", of course).

What you need in order to have this sort of map is some sense of being able to stratify $V_\kappa$ in a way that lets you well-order each of the levels uniformly. So, for example, in $L$, this would be the case with $<_L$. But in general? I don't see a reason why any such function exists.

Comment: I'll accept this until someone can come up with a reasonable map as it gives solid reasons for the non-existence of too explicit maps.